# how to get other users' full size profile picture in linkedin

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I would like to get someone's profile picture, the original one that he/she uploaded.

I have been trying it with this:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)
```

But I failed and the response is like this:

```json
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to people search denied.",
  "requestId": "XYK50W4DAD",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1429639373120
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

***Agree OAuth User Agreement:***

```
Default Scope:
    r_basicprofile
    r_fullprofile
```

Neither r_basicprofile nor r_fullprofile is checked for getting access to user profile.follow url can be use to fetch profile information from LinkedIn.

```
private static final String host = "api.linkedin.com"; 
private static final String topCardUrl = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,headline,picture-urls::(original))";
```

***Method to set app side permission***

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE,Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```

Comment: how to get education details, date of birth and skills?